# How Do I Replace Namespaces with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I have not used PHP in many years and I'm trying to manipulate RSS feeds of tweets in a way that requires the name of the tweeter. I'm currently pulling RSS feeds from TwitRSS and it is all working fine except the name of the tweeter uses a namespace so the element says tweeter name. I've seen many threads on this site about how to use the namespace and I've tried all of them with no success.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
$newsoutput = new SimpleXMLElement('http://twitrss.me/twitter_search_to_rss/?term=php', LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);
$newsoutput = json_decode(json_encode($newsoutput), TRUE);
foreach ($newsoutput['channel']['item'] as $item) {
echo $item['title']."<br>".$item['description']."<br>".$item['link']."<br>".$item['guid']."<br>".$item['pubDate']."<br>";
echo $item['author']."br";}
```

That of course works fine for all normal elements being echo's out, but whenever I try to get the namespace tag every solution I've tried has resulted in error messages in the loop. Usually it has to do with the child element being null.

Now I would like to try a different solution. I would like to do a string replace that would change every namespace element with a non-namespace element. Ideally the resulting RSS feed would have every element of  replaced with  and then echo'd out normally.

I've tried adding stuff like:

```
 $newsoutput->str_replace("dc:creator","author","");
```

I added it before the loop because I would assume that the array of item elements would have to be changed in the SimpleXML array before looping and echo'ing. I know one problem with what I am doing is that php str_replace expects 3 parameters and I can only think of two. The word I want to replace and what I want to replace it with. What else would I need? I also think that I might have to run a loop for the string replace before running the loop for the new namespace free feed.

Comment: oops, "tweeter name" should be surrounded by the tag with the namespace, but it got stripped out

Comment: `str_replace` is a global function. `->str_replace` is using class method. You obvioulsy do it wrong.

Comment: oops, author was left in there from a previous string replace attempt

Comment: And `str_replace` takes a string. Do you have a string in your code?

Comment: Don't remove the namespace (prefixes), you can fetch data inside a namespace (however it is easier with DOM).

Comment: Technically speaking, what really counts is the namespace URI (e.g. `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/`) and the namespace prefix (`dc`) could change any time. Yes, it's unlikely they'll ever change it (mostly because they'll break lots of third-party implementations) but it never hurts knowing it :)

Comment: Indeed, SimpleXML expects the namespace URI by default (in methods like `SimpleXMLElement::children()`) not the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of hacks copied from other examples which are making your life harder, not easier:

- you do not need `LIBXML_NO_CDATA`; it only makes a difference when you're turning the object back into XML anyway (it also makes a difference to the result of `print_r`, but you shouldn't rely on that anyway for "magic" objects like SimpleXMLElement)
- `$newsoutput = json_decode(json_encode($newsoutput), TRUE);` basically says "throw away all the useful bits of the SimpleXML API, and attempt to give me an array with no guarantee of its format"
- adding string manipulation on top of that is just adding hacks to hacks.

Instead, you should learn how to use namespaces with SimpleXML, which is by using [the `->children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) (and maybe also [the `->attributes()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php), which works the same way).

So you can just use something like this:

```
$newsoutput = new SimpleXMLElement('http://twitrss.me/twitter_search_to_rss/?term=php', 0, true);
foreach ($newsoutput->channel->item as $item) {
    echo $item['title']."<br>".$item['description']."<br>".$item['link']."<br>".$item['guid']."<br>".$item['pubDate']."<br>";
    echo $item->children('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/')->creator."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. In fact shortly after posting this I figured it out.

Comment: Now I've got the entirely new problem of echoing it out as its own RSS feed. The solution I have only produces the last line of the feed in your browser even though if you click on view source everything is there. The source also only shows up as a single line of code.

Comment: Should have said last item of the feed in the browser.

Comment: Not a problem I ever had in ASP.Net outputing databound grids as rss feeds. For some reason having a line of code in its own new line in Visual Studio was all I needed to do. Php seems different.

Comment: 1) If this answered the question, please accept it (with the tick icon); if you have another question, please ask it separately, as that makes it easier for others to find in future. 2) It doesn't matter how the browser displays the output, and whether the source code is all on one line or not; XML is a language for machines, not humans. Use an RSS reader or an RSS validation tool to check the output.